# Efficient way to bin sorted array in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a sorted array of floats a[0],...,a[n-1].

I am given a number `m<<n` which represents the number of equispaced bins.  How can I efficiently find the upper boundary of the bin that contains the most numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer posted by Tony D is not the most efficient. It is more efficient to call `lower_bound` for each value of the breaks.  Then, the cost would be O(mlog n) instead of O(n).

Comment: recursive and most efficient usually aren't uttered in the same breath.

Comment: Nice!  *"cost would be O(log n)"* should be O(m log n) though.

Comment: @TonyD: thanks. Actually, for the second bin you would start the lower_bound from the first entry after the first bin to the end (and not from beginning to end).  The bins are equi-spaced, so at the second bin you now look for an array of length (m-1)/m*n elements. So you do O(sum_{j=1}^m log([m-j]/m n))=O(sum_{j=0}^(m-1) log(n)+log([m-j]/m))=O(log(n))

Comment: @user189035 my impression is that the bin boundaries are equally spaced in the `a[0]..a[n-1]` numeric range, not in the number of elements they contain (or there'd be no "most populous bin" to find in the first place), but you're right again that the number of elements to search will keep decreasing, and on average by the amount you suggest....

Comment: @user189035 your conclusion of O(log n) is still eluding me though: the `m` individual `lower_bound` probes start at O(log n) and can be expected to reduce pretty linearly, so isn't the average number of elements `lower_bound` deals with about n/2, not reducing the per-`lower_bound` complexity from O(log n) and overall complexity from O(m log n)?

Answer (score 3):

The bins each span `(a[n-1] - a[0]) / m` values - rounded up if at all.  You'll need to do one pass over the data, during which you work out whether the data's crossed a bin boundary and if so reset a numbers-in-bin counter, otherwise increment that counter.  Before resetting and at the end - if the numbers-in-bin is the greatest you've seen, record the upper boundary of the bin in your upper-boundary-of-most-populous-bin "solution" variable.